# Where is the documentation for "@ references in Stack Exchange?"

Tags: support

I'm sorry to ask this here, but I can find no information on how to properly use @ to refer to other users.

For example, if I want to refer to someone else's answer--whose name is, say, "User Name"--it can't be simply a matter of writing @User Name. In fact, dealing with this whitespace issue is specifically why I went looking for an answer.

The way to do this may be completely self-evident--please go easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

> Username: `Hello World`
>
> Ping: `@HelloWorld` or  simply `@Hel`

> Username: `Uniforms For Sale`
>
> Ping `@UniformsForSale` or simply `@Uni`

> Username: `user12345`
>
> Ping `@user12345` or simply `@use`

Comment: I just tried the equivalent of `@HelloWorld` and that's exactly the text that appeared in the rendered Markdown. Am I correct to assume that this will ping Mr. World, regardless?

Comment: Yes, it will ping him, but you mustn't use code blocks there

Comment: Ok, great. I now see this notation elsewhere. Sometimes I have seen the @reference appear as hyperlinked, but this must have been the result of someone explicitly using hyperlinking Markdown behind the reference. (BTW, I assume you mean 'mustn't use code blocks' when I try to ping the user.  Not that I shouldn't use code blocks in my comment above.)

Answer (score 2):

When the [help center](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help) doesn't have the information you seek, check the [main Stack Exchange meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), starting with [questions tagged FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq). There is an [FAQ on comment @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

The main rules are:

- @-replies only work in comments. If you type `@` in a post, it's just an ordinary character, there's no way to notify a user via a post's content. (Also in chat with different rules that I won't discuss here.)
- You can only @-reply to a previous comment in the same post, to the poster, or to an editor of the post (plus a few more edge cases, see the FAQ for the full story).
- You can only have at most one @-reply in a comment.
- The author of the post you commented on is always notified, in addition to the user you @-addressed.
- Sometimes your @-mention will be erased when you post the comment. Don't worry, that only happens if that user would have been notified anyway without the @-mention.
- To notify a user, type `@` and the first letter of their username, and let completion happen. If you want to type the name, it's the full name without spaces, or a prefix of at least 3 letters. See the FAQ for the nitty-gritty on abbreviations when some users have similar names.

Comment: Great, that list of FAQs on the meta site is SO useful. Is there a good reason it's not linked to from the help center? A simple "For All Other Questions" entry that directs users to that page would save (*you* among others) a lot trouble!